# Why does my C++ code show segmentation fault in the following snippet of printing a linked list?

Tags: c++

I have this question  where i have to write a function for printing the full linked list. Could you explain why am I getting this error and how to fix it

```
/*
       Print elements of a linked list on console 
       head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list
       Node is defined as 
       struct Node
     {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
     }
   */
     void Print(Node *head)
     {
     cout<<"test";
     while(head->next!=NULL)
     {

         cout<<(head->data)<<endl;
         head=head->next;

     }

   }
```

?

Comment: what if you list is empty

Comment: pass NULL to Print, and will try to get next from NULL which does not exist.

Comment: What does your debgger say? You need to step through this code carefully to find the source of the problem. You're getting down-voted because you missed this step.

Answer (score 0):

You do not check your parameter head for NULL. If you call Print(NULL) you are trying to access the nullpointer and a segmentation fault may occur.

```
void Print(Node *head)
{
    if(head == nullptr) return;

    cout<<"test";
    while(head->next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<(head->data)<<endl;
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```